# Java Client and Server

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently working on a File Transfer Client and Server program.  I can request and receive one file but then when I try to request another, it doesn't work.  It gives me an IOException.

Process: Client prompts user to input a name, sends to server, server responds with file, and server should wait for another request while client prompts again for user to input a name.

I believe I'm not "Waiting" correctly on the server side.  Any help that would kick me into the right direction would help.

Client Code:

```
 BufferedReader consoleIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("What file do you want? ");
    name = consoleIn.readLine();
    int bytesRead;

    if(!name.equals("!")) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        DataInputStream serverData = null;

        while(!name.equals("!")) {
            //fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(name));
            socketOut.println(name);
            socketOut.flush();

            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();   
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
            }

            serverData = new DataInputStream(in);     

            String fileName = serverData.readUTF();       
            output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);       
            long size = serverData.readLong();      

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];       
            while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = serverData.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1)       
            {       
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);       
                size -= bytesRead;       
            }    


            System.out.print("What file do you want? ");
            name = consoleIn.readLine();
        }    
    }
```

Server Code:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted!");
            BufferedReader socketIn =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            //PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            String name;
            BufferedReader fileIn;
            String line;
            name = socketIn.readLine();
            System.out.println(name);

            while((!name.equals("!")) && (!name.equals("*"))) {

                File file = new File(rootDirectory, name);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                dis.readFully(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);       
                dos.writeUTF(file.getName());       
                dos.writeLong(bytes.length);       
                dos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);       
                dos.flush();    

                System.out.println("Sending: " + name); 
                os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
                os.flush();

                name = socketIn.readLine();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
```

Comment: why is fis.close() commented out?

Comment: You appear to be closing connections on the client side?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I close the connection on the client side if a ! mark is detected in the input.

Comment: What about `serverData.close();` and `output.close();` when you read a file?

Comment: @EvanKnowles wouldn't it just get reopened when it loops? I'm getting a null value on the server side when I try to readline again.

Comment: witch line throws IOException? server or client?

Comment: To reopen the connection, it would need to reconnect.

Comment: It would be good if you paste the exception stack trace also here.

Comment: @طاهر I just edited the code and provided a description of the new problem under tom's answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadocs for [Socket.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29):

> Closing the returned `InputStream` will close the associated socket.

So the client's `in` and `serverData` streams should be closed outside the loop.

Additional comments:

- There is no need to wrap the `while (!name.equals("!"))` in `if(!name.equals("!"))`
- Closing the DataInputStream will close the underlying InputStream

---

**Edit:**

There is also a bug in the server. It sends the file twice:

```
dos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
// ...
os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: This helped a little bit.  It stopped the IOException from occurring but now there is a different problem.  I just pasted the new code and it allows me to ask for another file which the server waits for.  After it receives the name of the second file, it shows "Sending: <NameOfFile>" but when I look to see if I received the file, it's not there.  I believe the client isn't handling another file and outputting it?